# Search regular expression in JavaScript

Tags: jquery, regex, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

The search for regular expression in array for JQuery autocomplete is not working correctly.

I have an array:

```
var names = [ "Jorn Zaefferer", "Scott Gonzalez", "John Resig" ];
```

Here is the autocomplete function of JQuery:

```
$( "#developer" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    var matcher = new RegExp('^'+request.term,'g');
    var arr=new Array();
            for(var i=0;i<names.length;i++)
    {
        var index=0;

        if(matcher.test(names[i])===true)              //not returning true
        {
            console.log("it is true");
            arr.push(names[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("not done");
        }
    }
    response(arr);
  }
});
```

The conditional statement:

```
if(matcher.test(names[i])===true)
```

in the code is not returning true. Why?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to remove the `g` flag on your regular expression as that can leave your regular expression object with state from one search to the next and can mess things up.  There should be no reason for it in your particular use of the regex.

Then, for further help, you probably need to show us what exactly you are searching for in that array that is never returning true.

When you do start getting matches, if you're trying to accumulate all the matches, you will need to move the initialization of the `arr` variable to before the `for` loop so it isn't reinitialized in every iteration of the `for` loop.

Comment: Option 'g' doesn't leave any garbage or state.  In fact, it has no effect with `test`.

Comment: @MarioRossi - The [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) for `.test()` states this: `As with exec (or in combination with it), test called multiple times on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the previous match.`  That would cause problems for the OP's code if they intend to find multiple matches.

Comment: I would have had difficulty believing that JavaScript behaves in that way even when `test`'s **target** changes if you had not said it.

Comment: @MarioRossi - same thing for `.exec()`.  They just store the index and start the next search from the index value - they don't keep track of whether the string is the same or not - it's up to the developer to use the `g` flag properly and it isn't needed here so it should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

If you log or otherwise debug contents of `request.term`, it will be much clearer to you (and us! :-) ).

Also, I think you need to move `var arr=new Array();` before the `for`.  `var index=0;` can be removed.

Comment: i have debugged the request.term it is fine , there are other ways of doing this tasks like jquery,gerp but i didn't understand why the if statement inside for loop  didn't return true